# Why is a graph $2$-connected if and only if it has an ear decomposition?

Tags: graph-theory

> Why is a graph $2$-connected if and only if it has an ear decomposition?

Reading the book "Introduction to Graph Theory" I have come across the following definition and statement:

[image]

why is this statement true ?

Suppose I have a graph $G$ that consist of a cycle $C$ and a path $P$ that share no vertices. Then $G$ has an ear decomposition ? Well, I can decompose $G$ into $P_o = C$ and $P_1 = P$ ? $P_o$ is a cycle and $P$ is an ear of $P_0 \cup P_1$ - $P$ is a maximal path whose interval vertices have degree $2$ in $G$ ? But $G$ is not connected and therefore is $0$-connected and not $2$-connected ?

[image]

Picture of the graph I've in mind.

Comment: The text only makes sense if it talks about *connected* graphs. Maybe that is a global convention in the text?

Comment: No, I'm afraid this is not stated explicitly. It's in a chapter on k-connectedness.

Comment: There is a page of errata for this book (see http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~west/igt/igt2err.html). The definition of ear has been adjusted.

Answer (score 3):

When making an ear decomposition, the end points of the path $P_i$ must already be in the existing graph $C \cup P_1 \cup ... \cup P_{i-1}$. Hence the Graph is connected, hope this helps.

Comment: (+1) And, indeed, the errata (now hosted at http://dwest.web.illinois.edu/igt/igt2err.html) say: *p163 - Def4.2.7: We must also require that the endpoints of the ear have degree at least 3 in G. (Sandi Klavzar)* This is equivalent to saying that the endpoints of the ear must already be in the graph built from all the previous ears.